# have nothing to do with it and had nothing to do with it

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, past-tense, grammaticality-in-context

context: Police interrogate a murder suspect (2 different movies)

suspect: ***I have nothing to do with it***

and

suspect: ***I had nothing to do with it***

question: why one uses have, and the other uses had? To me, ***had*** makes the most sense since it (murder) has already happened.

Answer (score 1):

If you change your question to refer to a kidnapping, the difference makes sense.

If the kidnap victim is still missing, then **have nothing** fits. The situation is on-going.

If the kidnap victim has been found dead, then **had nothing** works better. It's now an inquiry about a crime that has already been committed.

A suspect in a murder might also use **have nothing** if the murder / investigation is fresh; and **had nothing** if it related to events further in the past.

It's a question of context.